# custom serialization - ISerializable and protected/private constructor to deserialization

Tags: c#, constructor, deserialization, iserializable

I don't understand how it works: when I implement ISerializable interface I have to define protected (unless the class is sealed, in which case the constructor should be marked private) constructor: 
`protected MyClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)`
This access modifier makes this constructor unusable for any object in the project so how deserialization succeed?

Comment: The CLR can call a protected / private constructor if it wants. You can do the same thing using reflection.

Comment: Through [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) - prepare your mind to be blown : )

Comment: Are you trying to tell me that using reflection I can use private/protected constructors to make an instance of type which implement ones?

Comment: @djf I'm sorry for bothering you but I'm familiar with Reflection as much as Andrew Troelsen teach my with his book (Pro C# 5.0 And The NET 4.5 Framework) or I've just missed  this particular use. Troelsen didn't mention nothing about what is happening behind the scene of deserialzation. I was very curious and that is why I have asked. Thanks for response

Comment: @user2551229 the crucial point is that the constructor is parameterless, not that it's protected. During the deserialization of an object, a new instance is created first and then all of its fields are initialized. Have a look at these related questions; [Why XML-Serializable class need a parameterless constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267724/why-xml-serializable-class-need-a-parameterless-constructor), [Why do I need a parameterless constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561333/why-do-i-need-a-parameterless-constructor)

Comment: JSON.NET fails at finding protected constructors.  Just try to deserialize a DbUpdateConcurrencyException and it acts like it's missing the required constructor.